# How can I update a document found in a query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to update document found by a query. Actually I'm trying the following approach:

```
export const add_user = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    corsHandler(request, response, () => {

        const collectionReference = db.collection("users");    
        const query = collectionReference.where("name", "==", "John");

        fbid_query.get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                console.log("John notfound");
            } else {
                console.log("John found!");
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
                    add_update(query, "George");                    
                });
            }
            response.json([]);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            response.json([]);
        });
    });
});
```

.

```
const add_update = function (query, new_name) {
    query.get(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(document) {
            console.log("entered in forEach");
            document.ref.update({                   
                name: new_name
            }); 
        });
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("error: ", error);
    });    
}
```

The only `console.log` that appears is *success*, although nothing is updated and John indeed exists in Cloud Firestore.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I don't know if it matters but before I actually try to update, I call `query.get()` just to check if something exists (and after I call that approach to update).

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire function. The context is important here.  You're almost certainly not returning a promise that's resolved when all the async work is complete (or generating a response in the same situation).

Comment: @DougStevenson edited will full code.

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely not handling promises everywhere in your code correctly.  All the database API methods are async and return immediately with a promise that you need to use to track the work.  The entire function needs to return a promise that resolves only after all of the work is fully complete.  Which is going to require a lot of work on your part here.  The video series here may help you understand some of the things you need to do: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: But even if I did all wrong, the query should still be doing something, shouldn't it? I get the logs "John found!" and "success", meaning it found John in the first query call and that it tried to do the second query call, although it doesn't do anything on this second call.

Comment: No, if you don't return a promise, Cloud Functions will shut down your function, and any work that hasn't been finished may be terminated.  You really are obliged to deal with promises correctly, and there is no alternative.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: But how can the outer function know that the inner function's promise is over? Can I ever have 2 promisses in the same cloud function call?

Comment: What you are asking is fundamental to understanding promises.  I suggest you invest some time in learning how they work.  My video series that I linked has been found helpful for that.